# How come some people append f to the end of variables?

Tags: c++

In the tutorial I'm reading for OGRE3d [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Intermediate+Tutorial+1) the programmer is constantly adding `f` at the end of any variable he initializes, like `200.00f` or `0.00f` so I decided to erase `f` and see if it compiles and it compiles just fine, what is the point of adding `f` at the end of the variable?

EDIT: So you're saying if I initialize a variable with `200.03` it won't initialize it as a floating point but if I were to do so with `200.03f` it would? If not where does the f become useful then?

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean that it has the same meaning.

Comment: It appears to do the exact same thing though when I use it :\ so to me, the person who doesn't understand, it's doing the same thing, thus I'm asking whats going on here at SO.

Comment: A good answer would explain that the type may affect the value. For example, `.3f` is not equal to `.3`. There is a vote up waiting for somebody who adds this to their answer…

Comment: As a subtler example, `float x = 5 / 3f` and `float x = 5 / 3` will have two different values that may cause differences in corner cases.

Comment: @SLaks Doesn't compile - http://ideone.com/5V4kk3

Comment: @SLaks perhaps you're thinking of integer division? `float x = 5 / 3.0` vs `float x = 5 / 3`? http://ideone.com/uxscgL

Comment: @Slaks: I would consider that more overt. The change is larger and more readily noticed and is also a mistake that people learn to recognize and avoid. The difference between `.3f` and `.3` is smaller, more easily overlooked, and sometimes not well understood by people not versed in floating point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a way to specify that number has to be interpreted as a "float", not a "double" (which is the standard for C++ decimal numbers and uses up twice the memory).

This discussion could be of help:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/24483/

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9bk1wcy.aspx

> A floating-point constant without an f, F, l, or L suffix has type
>   double. If the letter f or F is the suffix, the constant has type
>   float. If suffixed by the letter l or L, it has type long double. For
>   example:

Answer (score 3):

`200.00f` is not a variable.  It can't *vary*.

It's a compile-time constant, with `float` representation.  The `f` signifies that it's a `float`.

By comparison, `200.00` would be interpreted as a `double`.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard states that constant floats are doubles which promotes the operation to a double.

```
float a,b,c;
...
a = b+7.1;  this is a double precision operation
...
a = b+7.1f;  this is a single precision operation
...
c = 7.1; //double
a = b + c; //single all the way
```

The double precision requires more storage for the constant, plus a conversion from single to double for the variable operand, then a conversion from double to single to assign the result.  With all the conversions going on if you are not in tune with how floating point works, rounding and such you might not get the result you were thinking you were going to get.  The compiler may at some point in the path optimize some of this behavior out, making it either harder to understand the real problems and the fpu in the hardware might accept mixed mode operands, also hiding what is really going on.

It is not just a speed problem but also accuracy.  There was a recent SO question, pretty much the same problem, why does this comparison work with one number and not another.  Take the fraction 5/11ths for example  0.454545....  Lets say, hypothetically, you had base 10 fpu with single precision of 3 significant digits and a double of 6 significant digits.

```
float a = 0.45454545454;
...
if(a>0.4545454545) b=1;
...
```

well in our hypothetical system we can only store three digits into a, so a = .455 because we are using by default a round up rounding mode.  but our comparision will be considered double because we didnt put the f at the end of the number.  the double version is 0.454545. a is converted to a double which results in 0.455000, so:

```
if(0.455000>0.454545) b = 1;
```

0.455 is greater than 0.454545 so b would be a 1.

```
float a = 0.45454545454;
...
if(a>0.4545454545f) b=1;
...
```

so now the comparison is single precision so we are comparing 0.455 to 0.455 which is not greater, so b=1 does not happen.

When you write floating point constants that is base 10 decimal, the floating point numbers in the computer are base 2 and they dont always convert smoothly just like 5/11 would work just fine in base 11 but in base 10 you get an infinite repeating digit.  0.1 in decimal for example creates a repeating pattern in binary.  Depending on where the mantissa cuts off the rounding can make that lsbit of the mantissa round up or not (also depends on the rounding mode you are using if the floating point format you are using even has rounding).  Which of itself creates problems depending on how you use the variable as the comparison above shows.

For non-floating point the compiler usually saves you, but sometimes doesnt:

```
unsigned long long a;
...
a = ~3;
a = ~(3ULL);
...
```

Depending on the compiler and computer the two assignments can give you different results one MIGHT give you 0x00000000FFFFFFFC another MIGHT give 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC.

If you want something specific you should be quite clear when you tell the compiler what you want otherwise the compiler takes a guess and doesnt always make the guess that you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the value is to be interpreted as a single-precision floating point variable (type `float`). Without the f-suffix, it is interpreted as a double-precision floationg point variable (type `double`).

This is usually done to shut up compiler warnings about possible loss of precision by assigning a double value to a float variable. When you didn't receive such a warning you maybe have switched off warnings in your compiler settings (which is bad!).

But it can also have subtile syntactical meaning. As you know C++ allows functions which have the same name but differ by the types of their parameters. In that case the f suffix can determine which function is called.

Comment: Unless it doesn't have a decimal point at all, in which case it's interpreted as an `int` - probably the most common source of error from this kind of thing.